# How to store Reorderable list sequence to mysql database

Tags: flutter, reorderable-list

I'm creating a Reorderable list of products so that when a person reorder the list, the list sequence should be sent to php file and then store in the database.
The products data is being fetched from the api using FutureBuilder.

**This is the code for Reorderable list with FutureBuilder**

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _productList,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ReorderableListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  key: ValueKey(index),
                  isThreeLine: true,
                  leading: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https://etsalcard.com/" +
                          snapshot.data[index].prodSerImage.toString(),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].prodSerName.toString()),
                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].prodSerPrice.toString()),
                  trailing: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                      IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                setState(() {
                  if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                    newIndex -= 1;
                  }
                  final item = snapshot.data.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  snapshot.data.insert(newIndex, item);
                });
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
          }
        },
      ),
```

**My Reorderable list looks like this**

[image]

The reorder Function is working perfectly. The question is how could I get the sequence of list to store in the database or is there some other way to do so.

I've tried sending the changed list sequence through the multidimensional list but don't know how to extract it in php file.

**This is the code for storing changed list data to multidimensional list**

```
    

onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                setState(() {
                  if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                    newIndex -= 1;
                  }
                  final item = snapshot.data.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  snapshot.data.insert(newIndex, item);


                 Data card = Data(
                id: snapshot.data[index].id,
                oldLocation: oldIndex.toString(),
                newLocation: newIndex.toString(),
              );
               cards.add(card);

                });
              },
```